# It shows same comments on different pages in disqus

Tags: javascript, php, disqus

I am making a forums section for my website where disqus comments are loaded according to the question asked by user. I have tried setting page tile, page url, page identifier. But even then it shows same comments on all pages. Don't know where I am going wrong?
Here is my code

```
<script>
    var disqus_config = function () {
        this.page.url = "http://localhost:3000/forums_details.php?que=<?php echo $_GET['que']; ?>";
        this.page.identifier = "<?php echo $_GET['que']; ?>";
    };
    (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
        var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
        s.src = '//onlinestudymaterial.disqus.com/embed.js';
        s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
        (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
     })();
</script>
```

Comment: I think that's because your localhost. Try to setting your public IP (if you have open the port 3000 in your router pointing to your machine). However, that's a poor quality question. You have more explanation in the subject than in the body of the question. Try to edit the question and add the information (the returned error, the expected result, etc). You'll obtain better answers, or at least, answers.